# Is there a Big Five personality assessment under an open-commercial license?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, personality, behavior, big-five

I am currently working on a project with a few students. It's an app that can test the big 5 personality test. The problem is, I am having trouble finding one that is under an open license and that we could use. We are currently using a free non-commercial use for research purposes, but we are starting to explore the possibility of using it commercially one day.

**Please list even ones that we might have to pay for.**

Comment: I answered a related question https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/canonical-literature-for-big-5-personality-theory/18268#18268

Answer (score 3):

**IPIP Scales:**
The IPIP scales are in the public domain: https://ipip.ori.org/
They are intended to have no restrictions on use (see https://ipip.ori.org/newPermission.htm ).
See in particular, the section on [multi-construct inventories](https://ipip.ori.org/newMultipleconstructs.htm). I think the most popular Big Five measures would be

- [Big Five Aspects Scale](https://ipip.ori.org/BFASKeys.htm): It has 100 items and measures the Big Five as well as 2 aspects per Big Five. It's a nice compromise between just measuring the Big Five and the much longer facet-level measures (e.g., NEO PI R, IPIP NEO 300, etc.)
- [Goldberg's IPIP 50](https://ipip.ori.org/newBigFive5broadKey.htm).
- [IPIP NEO 50](https://ipip.ori.org/newNEODomainsKey.htm)
- [IPIP NEO 300](https://ipip.ori.org/newNEOFacetsKey.htm). This is modelled on the NEO PI R. So it measures 30 facets as well as the Big Five that are designed to be similar to the NEO PI R.

A major difference between Goldberg's IPIP 50 and IPIP NEO 50 is the openness factor. For Goldberg it is intellectance (i.e., intellectual engagement and self-rated intellect), whereas IPIP NEO 50 is openness to experience (i.e., some intellectual engagement, but also creative interests, unconventionality, etc.).

**LEFFI**: The [Less Evaluative Five Factor Inventory](https://osf.io/kfz28/wiki/home/) is a new measure that is explicitly in the Public Domain (disclosure: it was developed by  Joshua Wood and me). It is designed to have lower levels of item-level social desirability than some measures of the Big Five.